# Check if email already exist

Tags: php, database, mysqli

How do I check if the email already exist in the database and deny the registration?

MySQL was the one taught to me and I'm currently on a wall using MySQLi.

Here is the code that I'm currently working on using MySQLi:

```
<?php 
$cookie_name = "loggedin";

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "scholarcaps";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Database connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $phash = sha1(sha1($pass."salt")."salt");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' AND password='$phash';";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($count == 1)
    {
        $cookie_value = $user;
        setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (180), "/");
        header("Location: personal.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Username or password is incorrect!";
    }
}
else if (isset($_POST['register']))
{
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $phash = sha1(sha1($pass."salt")."salt");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, email, username, password) VALUES ('','$email', '$user', '$phash');";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: make a query to check if the emailaddress is already present. Implement this query in your code and you're done.

Comment: is your email  = username ?

Comment: did you get this answered?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because the solutions to the duplicate are completely irrelevant to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite using `mysqli` your code is still vulnerable to sql injection as you directly embed variables in the sql statements - use prepared statements to avoid nasty surprises. The following is not tested but should show how you can use prepared statements. There are better ways of hashing the password - such as [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and also [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) though these are not available in PHP versions prior to 5.5

```
$response=array();
$cookie_name='loggedin';


$dbhost =   'localhost';
$dbuser =   'root'; 
$dbpwd  =   ''; 
$dbname =   'scholarcaps';
$db =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );




if( isset( $_POST['login'] ) ) {

    $user  = $_POST['username'];
    $pass  = $_POST['password'];
    $phash = sha1( sha1( $pass . "salt" ) . "salt" );

    $sql='select `username`, `password` from `users` where `username`=? and `password`=?';
    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

    if( $stmt ){

        $stmt->bind_param( 'ss', $username, $phash );
        $result=$stmt->execute();

        if( !$result ) $response[]='Query failed';


        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result( $name, $pwd );
        $stmt->fetch();

        if( $stmt->num_rows()==0 ) $response[]='No such user';
        else {

            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
            $db->close();

            setcookie( $cookie_name, $user, time() + 180, "/" );
            exit( header( "Location: personal.php" ) );
        }


        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();
        $db->close();

        /* show errors */
        if( !empty( $response ) ){
            echo '<ul><li>',implode('</li><li>',$response),'</li></ul>';
        }
    }

} elseif( $_POST['register'] ){

    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    $phash = sha1( sha1( $pass . "salt" ) . "salt" );



    /* Does the email address already exist? */

    $emailfound=false;

    $sql='select `email` from `users` where `email`=?';
    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
    if( $stmt ){

        $stmt->bind_param('s',$email);
        $result=$stmt->execute();
        if( $result ){
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result( $emailfound );
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->free_result();
        }
    }

    if( $emailfound ){
        echo 'Sorry, that email address already exists in our database. Please try again with a different address.';
        $stmt->close();
        $db->close();

    } else {

        /* the `id` should be automatically generated I assume - hence being omitted here */
        $sql='insert into `users` (`email`, `username`, `password`) values (?,?,?);';
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

        if( $stmt ){

            $stmt->bind_param( 'sss', $email, $username, $phash );
            $result=$stmt->execute();

            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
            $db->close();

            if( $result ) header('Location: login.php');
            else{
                /* failed to register the user */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [passord_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) by ircmaxell brings the `password_*` functions to php >= 5.3.7

Comment: thanks man this is working, and yes ill study the other hashing techniques.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by setting my email column with unique attribute. After the registration submit you can catch the `mysqli_errno()`. So you will see if there is a duplicate entry.

You will save a check-query with this solution.

Comment: When implementing this approach you need to take into account that all key violations will trigger the same error code and there's no built-in rock-solid method to find out which key it was. If there're several candidates (and this seems to be the case because I presume `username` has to be unique as well) you'll have to mess with parsing error messages to extract the key name.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,
add this code after `sha1`

```
$result = mysql_query("select COUNT(id)  from users where email='".$email."'");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count > 0){
    echo "email exist";
}else
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, email, username, password) VALUES ('','$email', '$user', '$phash');";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to match the email, you just want to make sure an email address exists, you could...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' AND password='$phash' AND email<>'';";
```

or, to specify a minimum length...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' AND password='$phash' AND LEN(email) > 0;";
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this php function for get record count in db

```
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result)
```

after check it more than 0 or not